# PostgreSQL sequence with specific formula for next value

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a column(bigint) in my table and I want every next value of it automatically be twice of previous (starting from one). How can I do it with sequences?

Comment: It can not be done with sequences - they only guarantee that the next value will be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a `SEQUENCE`. You must, to generate each value:

```
 BEGIN;
 LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
 INSERT INTO mytable (id, blah) VALUES ( (SELECT max(id) * 2 FROM mytable), 'blah' );
 COMMIT;
```

The `LOCK` and transaction block are important, otherwise two concurrent transactions can get the same value.

This is a variant of the "gapless sequence" problem (see Google). Like there, my general advice is: don't do it. Instead, use an ordinary sequence to generate IDs if you don't have a natural key, then calculate the value on demand. In this case, double-the-previous-row is the same as saying "two to the power of the row number", so you can write:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  2 ^ row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS generated_id
FROM mytable;
```